# Whats better for performance? A list, or getting info from a database?

Tags: java, mysql, performance

So, I have a server with limited resources. (3Gb of RAM)
What I need to know is, is it better to use this

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
void init(){
    list = loadListFromDatabase
}
```

And add or remove to the list when needed, or, when I need the object, load it from the database every time its accessed?

Comment: Use the latter since the data for the object in database may be modified by another transaction.

Comment: it depends. does you code usually end up accessing most of the objects? in this case it might be quicker to load it all up front. or does you code only access a few records, infrequently? is so, maybe load on demand.

Comment: Well, not every object is constantly being accessed, but the ones that are, are being accessed frequently. 

With the list, which is how I currently do it, I edit the Object, then re-add it to the list

Comment: The bottleneck may be opening connections manually i.e. using `Class.forName(...); DriverManager.getConnection(...);`. You should use a connection pool to improve the database connection time and reduce the memory impact. Also, you may add indexes to your database table in order to fetch the desired row(s) faster.

Comment: I actually use something 'like' a connection pool, so thats not a problem, all of my tables have indexe

Comment: for high access, i guess the fastest approach would be. 1. load using a single statement. 2. do all you access and mods on the list. 3. for all objects which have CHANGED, write back using a single batch update. And a single batch insert for any new records.

Comment: AFAIK ehcache handle 2nd level cache forother framework like Hibernate that can help you to accomplish this instead handling it manually.

Answer (score 1):

some suggestions for you,

If you have a heavy database like 50+ tables, million of records then try to minimize database accesses.
for low size databases (in your case) database access wont matter much.

but processing speed of RAM is faster than DB access

if you are using multithreading in your application which are interacting/modifying/reading with same table(object table in your case) then dont go for fetching all in memory and processing, rather fetch it from DB everytime.

if your code is sequential or that table is independent (no other block is modifying same table) then fetching in memory at once process it and then store it back to db is efficient.

Another factor you should consider is memory size, if you have low memory (you are mentioning that 3GB RAM) then first option is better i.e. fetch from DB everytime.

all you app is deployed on single machine with 3gb ram, if yes then please find out memory consumption of your application without any load that is benchmark that your application requires atleast that amount of memory

after analysing your stats, accordingly take decision.